# Appending one sheets range onto the end of another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, excel-2016

I have an issue that I didn't last night. The code below was working fine. I have a sales tracker of sorts, and I'm working on importing our rosters that get exported as Excel sheets instead of entering hours manually. I have that part sorted. It's one workbook, with 1 week per sheet, total of 5 sheets. Names in the first column, dates across the top. I have code that imports the 5 sheets into the tracker, removes the first column (name column) from sheets 2-5, and the following code appends to the last column of week 1 (or sheet 1), and then once merged, deletes sheets 2-5. Was working no problem. Now it gets halfway, and a) sits there spinning its wheels, or b) crashes Excel. It seems to be getting stuck on the Sub below. If I comment it out, it runs fine.

```
Sub MergeSheets()
    Dim NextCol As Long
    NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("A1:XX100").Copy Sheets("1").Cells(1, NextCol)

    NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("A1:XX100").Copy Sheets("1").Cells(1, NextCol)

    NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4").Range("A1:XX100").Copy Sheets("1").Cells(1, NextCol)

    NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("5").Range("A1:XX100").Copy Sheets("1").Cells(1, NextCol)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a small mistake, but it is important - you are not referencing the parent of the `Column` and it is taking the active sheet.

Try like this:

```
Sub MergeSheets()

    Dim NextCol As Long

    With Sheets("1")
        NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("2").Range("A1:XX100").Copy .Cells(1, NextCol)

        NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("3").Range("A1:XX100").Copy .Cells(1, NextCol)

        NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("4").Range("A1:XX100").Copy .Cells(1, NextCol)

        NextCol = Sheets("1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("5").Range("A1:XX100").Copy .Cells(1, NextCol)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say where the issue is exactly.  You have a bad setup.  You are appending 648 Columns * 4 each time that you run your code.  There are only 16384 columns in the current Excel format.  After running your code 25 times you will be out of room.  Even though you're probably only going to run it 13 times (1 years worth of data); it is still a bad setup. You should consider changing your design.

```
Sub MergeSheets()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NextCol As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
        For Each ws In Sheets(Array("2", "3", "4", "5"))
            ws.Range("A1:XX100").Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
        Next
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```